# AWS S3 sync method- possible to ignore modified files completely?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm purposefully modifying every locally synced files (although directory name is unique and unmodified), which makes the sync method try to redownload the whole bucket, taking an excess of time.

Copying the local files (to preserve their timestamp + size) isn't really an option since the bucket size is so big, and AWS sync docs don't seem to have an option to exclude modified files.

I was hoping there's a way to prevent attempting to redownload a directory if it exists locally.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This sounds like it beyond the capabilities of `aws s3 sync`, which tries to synchronise files so they match. Have you tried any other method (eg copying via a Python script)? How many files are there in total, and how many are different each time you want to sync? Are they being stored locally in a hierarchy of directories, or is it just flat storage?

Comment: Thanks, that ended up working. I suppose it makes sense to want synced files to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

Would `aws s3 sync --size-only` work for you?

> `--size-only` (boolean) Makes the size of each key **the only criteria** used to decide whether to sync from source to destination.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately that doesn't work. As a side note to anyone curious: because the directories already exist locally, the sync method can't actually overwrite them, so nothing so modified. But, it definitely takes hundreds of times longer to update than if we could just ignore modified files.

Comment: So you want to download any new (locally missing) files, but do not touch any existing files which are already out of sync? Maybe it's a job for a small Python script, and not for `aws s3 sync`. List all files in the bucket, subtract from it the list of all files in the tree, download the rest.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this today. Thanks to both of you for the script idea